# Deleting point data from ArcGIS Online

Tags: point, arcgis-online, delete

I am creating point data for Drainage using ArcGIS online. But I accidentally created a few points that  I do not require.

Is there any way that I can delete the record from the attribute table in the ArcGIS Online environment?

Comment: If you have the objectID you can delete (with the correct privileges) using REST API https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013805

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to follow these steps provided by ArcGIS Online documentation [Delete a feature](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector-classic/windows/collect-data/delete-a-feature.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3544825EF7814189AB7F37ACA0E56EE2)

> Locate a feature on the map and delete it.
>
> Select the damage assessment you want to remove, and delete it by doing one of the following:
> If you see a list of results, select More More to the right of the feature you're deleting to see a menu of the actions you can take with that feature, and select Delete.
>
> If you select a feature that is isolated from the others, select Delete at the bottom of the panel.
>
> The message You are about to delete this feature displays. Select Delete to confirm that you want to delete the feature. The feature is removed from the map.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to know that the feature layer has “Add, update, and delete features” enabled that can be done through these steps. It will help to delete any point or line or polygon through the pop-up. But if the above option is not enabled, the pop-up will not show the delete option. 
Log in to your ArcGIS Online account.
Go to my content and find the feature Layer from where you want to delete a record 
Click on the Feature Layer. 
Find Settings on your right and click on it.
Scroll down the page and look for Feature Layer (Hosted), editing, and then “What kind of editing is allowed?” You can find five options with radio buttons. 
Select the “Add, update, and delete features.” Save the changes.
Now go to the map and select the point to be deleted. 
The pop-up will appear. Scroll down the pop-up and look for delete. 
Click on the delete. Done.